# Pass arguments to Spring Boot RUN method in scala

Tags: scala, spring-boot

I am trying to pass arguments to the run method, but since the run method is overloaded, the scala is not able to figure out the overloaded methods

```scala
object Entry {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    SpringApplication.run(classOf[Entry],args) // How to pass the arguments?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```scala
SpringApplication.run(classOf[Entry],args(0))
```

This works for my requirement

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
SpringApplication.run(classOf[Entry], args:_*)
```